# React app embedded in Spring MVC/Rest: browser GET request routing

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, spring-mvc, react-router-v4

so I have a Java/Spring MVC web app, which has a `@Controller` with a method annotated `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)` returning the main *index.html* (when `localhost:8080` is typed in browser url), containing the React.js app. This is the only controller for a `text/html`, all the others are `@RestController`s mapped to path `/api...` - restfull api for the React SPA. The React app has implemented the *react-router-dom* and the programmatic routing in the app works fine, f.e. a `<Link to="/dashboard">dashboard</Link>` got to the `http://localhost:8080/dashboard` and is not sending a GET to the server.
  The problem is when I manually type `http://localhost:8080/dashboard` in the browser url, it sends a GET request to the Spring server, whereas when a React app is served by *node runtime*, the react-router-dom "catches" and handles these browser requests. Can the these text/html browser requests be forced to be handled by the react router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using react's BrowserRouter.

When you type a url into your browser and press ENTER you're making a GET http request to the server. When navigating with react's Link elements, your browser resolves the url changes and renders the react component according to the url value without making a request.

Hope this helps

Comment: I just don't understand, when a react app is launched with babel-node, or react-scripts start, the react router resolves the url typed in the browser + ENTER. But served from Java/Jetty I get a 404. Thanks tho

Comment: Because BrowserRouter assumes that your server can resolve any view requests. If your first request is to /index and your server resolves the view and then you navigate to /users through a link, then the browser renders the <User/> component (assuming /users renders <User/>). But if you enter /users in your search bar and press enter, then your server will have to resolve the /users view. If this behavior is undesirable, you can use HashRouter which resolves urls like #users.

Comment: babel-node also would have to resolve the view for the /users request

Comment: When you launch your web app using Jetty and go to http://localhost:8080/ (to get index.html) are you getting 404 as well?

Comment: no, for localhost:8080 I get the view (react app), but for f.e. localhost:8080/users I get a 404

Comment: That's because you don't have any @Controller that maps /users. When using babel-node , a client side app is created for you to test and play. When deploying to a real server you should use HashRouter if your app cannot resolve any other route besides '/'.

Comment: I found a workarround - sending redirect for every GET request with path other than "/" or "/api/**" to "/" somehow magically works. But I'm goung to checkout the HashRouter, never tried it yet..

Comment: But if you do that then all GET requests to any mapping will respond with index.hml

Comment: I'm fixing that with @PathVariables